# theorem relating determinants a linear system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove square homogeneous system $AX = \vec{0}$ has a nonzero solution $x$ iff $|A| = 0$

### Attempt

First, we suppose $AX = 0$ has a solution which is nontrivial, say $X = (x_1,...,x_n)$. Assume on the contrary that $|A| \neq 0$, thus $A$ is nonsingular and can be reduced to $I$, thus $AX = 0$ is equivalent to $IX= 0$ which implies that $x = (0,...,0)$ contradiction.

Now, suppose $|A| = 0$. Denote $R_1,...,R_n$ the rows of $A$. If $x=0$ is solution to $Ax = 0$, then we would have

$$ 0R_1 + ... + 0 R_n = 0$$

So the the rows are linearly independent. Can we conclude from here that $A$ must be non-singular; that is $|A| \neq 0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part of your proof looks good. For the second part, we assume $|A|=0$. Then $A$ cannot be row-equivalent to the identity matrix $I$. In particular, the rows of $A$ are not linearly independent--if they were, then $A \sim I$, which we have already noted is impossible. Therefore, since we know that $x=0$ is always a solution to the equation $Ax=0$, we can use the fact that the rows of $A$ are linearly dependent to construct another solution to the equation. This new solution will be non-trivial. I'll leave the details of exactly how to prove that to you, but that's the main idea. Use the fact that the rows of $A$ are linearly dependent to construct a second, non-trivial solution to $Ax=0$.

Comment: So, you are saying that since $|A|=0$, then the rows $R_1,..,R_n$ must be dependent? Well, if this the case, then we can find constancs $c_1,...,c_n$ not all zero such that $\sum c_i R_i = 0$ so our solution we are looking for is $(c_1,...,c_n)$. is this correct?

Comment: Yes, although I guess I'm used to thinking about this using columns, not rows. I.e., since |A|=0, the columns of A are not linearly independent, which means you can find some $x=(c_1, \ldots, c_n)$ are you described. We can certainly analogize everything to speak about rows instead of columns, but the way I learned linear algebra was by studying the columns of $A$ rather than the rows of $A$. But for this question, those are basically equivalent.